# Coral UI select not allowing to remove all values

Tags: xml, aem

I have a custom fragment template with custom metadata schema added for business use.
One field is a multi value dropdown. I can add values to it but when I remove all values and save it, it does not save the changes. (The last saved value(s) is saved again)

Basically, its forcing me to keep at least 1 value saved.
The schema is like:

```
<_x0031_480609690955
jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/select"
fieldLabel="My Dropdown"
multiple="true"
name="./jcr:content/metadata/mydropdown"
renderReadOnly="true">
<granite:data
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    metaType="dropdown"/>
<items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
    <_x0031_480609702507
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        text="Value 1"
        value="value_1"/>
    <_x0031_480609703314
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        text="Value 2"
        value="value_2"/>
    <_x0031_480609706365
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        text="Value 3"
        value="value_3"/>
</items>
```

Do I need to add some additional attributes here ?

Comment: Try adding ‘emptyOption=true’ this should add an empty field and hopefully save as an empty propery when selected.

Comment: @AhmedMusallam , I tried that too, but then author will  have to select this empty value every time they want to clear the dropdown. This could be my last option though.

Comment: What version of AEM are you on? If the latest you have two options, 1. Add a custom script to do the functionality you want. 2. Open a ticket with adobe to fix it, looks like a bug to me.